# Angular 9: how can I create a .ts file alone?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, ng-generate

I'm new to Angular and now I want to create only a `.ts` file and not a whole component, can you please tell me how can I do it with `ng generate`?

Use-Case :
While building the application I want to write the build version to a `.ts`.I want to load this file when this build is deployed and display the build version to user.

Comment: What do you mean by "generated"? Why not simply created such a file?

Comment: you are right I created it normally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [angular documents](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), you should specify exactly what your file is. It could be a function, class, interface, service, component, etc. For example, just create a file named `letters.function.ts` like this:

```
export function letters (){
   // do something
}
```

To facilitate creating more complicated stuff like components or services, it is recommended to use [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/). For instance:

```
ng generate component letters
ng generate service letters
ng generate interface letters
ng generate class letters
```

Answer (score 5):

you can create class using [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/) with `ng g class className`

Answer (score 0):

What I think you mean by this is you want somewhere to put common functions, so in that case you would create a [service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services). The `ng generate` command in that case is `ng generate service`. You can then inject the service into the components where you need it.